# Google Speech-to-Text API - android app crashing

Tags: java, android, google-api, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am new to this and I was trying to use **Google Speech-to-Text API** mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/SpeechRecognitionClient). I have followed the steps mentioned by them and have placed the `credentials.json` in the desired folder after creating a service account. I generated a signed apk to run it on an android device but every time I say something it crashes. I checked the logs it gives me this error:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.cloud.examples.speechrecognition, PID: 29178
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)[B in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:101)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.api.client.util.PemReader.readNextSection(PemReader.java:106)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.api.client.util.PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(PemReader.java:135)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.privateKeyFromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:296)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:286)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:210)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:174)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:141)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.examples.speechrecognition.MainActivity$mSpeechClient$2$1$1.getCredentials(MainActivity.kt:62)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.examples.speechrecognition.MainActivity$mSpeechClient$2$1$1.getCredentials(MainActivity.kt:45)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:140)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.stub.GrpcSpeechStub.create(GrpcSpeechStub.java:94)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.stub.SpeechStubSettings.createStub(SpeechStubSettings.java:126)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.<init>(SpeechClient.java:144)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:126)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.examples.speechrecognition.MainActivity$mSpeechClient$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:61)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.examples.speechrecognition.MainActivity$mSpeechClient$2.invoke(MainActivity.kt:45)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.examples.speechrecognition.MainActivity.getMSpeechClient(Unknown Source:7)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.cloud.examples.speechrecognition.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.kt:101)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1363)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7444)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3805)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3870)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1788)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7036)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
02-12 12:35:22.504 29178 29178 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: That may happen if you are using proguard and obfuscate your code. Check if there is anything you need to add, or at your release build section put `minifyEnabled false` to see if the error is resolved.

Comment: In the release build section `minifyEnabled false` is already present

Answer (score 0):

May be you do not have added library which contains : **org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64**

You can create your own method :

Decode Data:

```
    // decode data from base 64
    private static byte[] decodeBase64(String dataToDecode)
    {
        byte[] dataDecoded = Base64.decode(dataToDecode, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return dataDecoded;
    }
```

Encode Data:

```
    //enconde data in base 64
    private static byte[] encodeBase64(byte[] dataToEncode)
    {
        byte[] dataEncoded = Base64.encode(dataToEncode, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return dataEncoded;
    }
```

Hope it will helps.

Comment: This code is given as an example by google and I have downloaded it from their Github repository as mentioned in the link. So where should I add this?